# How to do Boxplot in R with subset?

Tags: r

I have a data called "gov", and it contain 6 different regime types(from 0 to 5), I want to make Boxplots of the score and rank with a box for each regime type. How can I do this? Thanks!
The data looks something like this.

```
regime    EstScore1   rank1  EstScore2  rank2
1         1.33        92       0.77      70
0         0.17        80       0.18      79
2         0.36        70       0.41      67
3         0.91        85       0.87      80
4         1.12        65       1.05      68
5         0.02        87       0.14      85
3         0.65        80       0.47      82
2         1.13        68       1.07      65
........
```

Comment: `boxplot(EstScore1~regime,data=gov)`?

Answer (score 0):

Using ggplot2 you can do as follow:

```
# Packages -------------------------
library(ggplot2)

# Data -----------------------------
data <- data.frame(
  regime = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
  rank1 = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 75, sd = 25)
)

# boxplot ---------------------------
  ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(regime), y = rank1)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Regime", y = "Rank")
```

Notice that here you have to convert regime to factors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = gov, 
       aes(y = EstScore1, x = rank1, colour=factor(regime))
       ) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]